# R - how to get coeffients for each column ~ timeline from a "spread" matrix?

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

I want to collect the linear regression coefficients for each column ~ ind.

Here is my data:

```
temp <- data.frame(
  ind = c(1:10),
  `9891` = runif(10, 15, 75),
  `7891` = runif(10, 15, 75),
  `5891` = runif(10, 15, 75)
)
```

I had tried

```
result = data.frame()

cols <- colnames(temp)[-1]

for (code in cols) {
  fit <- lm(temp[, code] ~ temp$ind)
  coef <- coef(fit)['ind']
  result$ind <- code
  result$coef <- coef
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Can anyone fix my method, or provides a better solution?
Also, I was wondering if `lapply()` and `summarise_at()` can do the work.

Thank you!

Comment: I have more than 10k columns in the original matrix, so I am looking for an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Your sample data contains 4 columns; but in the `for` loop you are trying to access 10 columns. Is that a typo? Also, the first column is `ind` so in the first step you're fitting a model `lm(temp$ind ~ temp$ind)`.

Comment: @Maurits Evers

 I have updated the code. The first fit should be `temp$X9891 ~ temp$ind`.

Comment: This is so wrong. The fact that you are asking this particular question strongly suggests that you have no idea regarding the reasons for NOT doing this. The statistical  concept to examine more carefully is "multiple comparisons".

Comment: This is purely a coding question. Moreover, the variables in the original dataset do not have any dependency. I do not concern statistical meaning for this particular case, and I only interest in collecting coefficient. Anyway, thank you for the information about multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `summarise_at` option

```
temp %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-contains("ind")), list(coef = ~list(lm(. ~ ind)$coef))) %>%
    unnest()
#  X9891_coef X7891_coef X5891_coef
#1  25.927946 52.5668120  35.152330
#2   2.459137  0.3158741   1.013678
```

The first row gives the offset and the second row the slope coefficients.

Or to extract only the slope coefficient and store the result in a long `data.frame`

```
temp %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-contains("ind")), list(coef = ~list(lm(. ~ ind)$coef[2]))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    stack() %>%
    setNames(c("slope", "column"))
#        slope     column
#  1 2.4591375 X9891_coef
#  2 0.3158741 X7891_coef
#  3 1.0136783 X5891_coef
```

PS. It's always good practice to include a fixed random seed when working with random data to ensure reproducibility of results.

---

### Sample data

```
set.seed(2018)
temp <- data.frame(
  ind = c(1:10),
  `9891` = runif(10, 15, 75),
  `7891` = runif(10, 15, 75),
  `5891` = runif(10, 15, 75)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply`

```
sapply(temp[-1], function(x) coef(lm(x ~ temp$ind))[2])

#X9891.temp$ind X7891.temp$ind X5891.temp$ind 
#   -0.01252979    -2.94773367     2.57816244
```

To get the final daatframe, you could do

```
data.frame(ind = names(temp)[-1], 
 coef = sapply(temp[-1], function(x) coef(lm(x ~ temp$ind))[2]), row.names = NULL)

#      ind        coef
#1   X9891 -0.01252979
#2   X7891 -2.94773367
#3   X5891  2.57816244
```

where every row represents value from the column.

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
temp <- data.frame(
   ind = c(1:10),
  `9891` = runif(10, 15, 75),
  `7891` = runif(10, 15, 75),
  `5891` = runif(10, 15, 75)
)
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried the `sapply`, however, it showed this error when the original data contains `NA`: 

```Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases 
```
 I think `sapply` is another elegant method, could you have a check on this case? Thank you!

Comment: @J.D As mentioned in the error message if you have all values as `NA` in a column it would give you the error message. You could find out those columns by `sapply(temp[-1], function(x) all(is.na(x)))` Or with `colSums(!is.na(temp[-1]), na.rm = TRUE) == 0`

Comment: Thank you for your instruction! After I excluded all-NA columns, the result becomes exactly what I need. I used the ```sapply(temp[-1], function(x) all(is.na(x)))```